# How to carry a string over from one chain to another in iptables?

Tags: linux, iptables

Here's what I'd like to do.

In my rule file (which I use with `iptables-restore`) I have (with limits removed):

```
-4 -A LOGDROP -j LOG --log-prefix "ipt:4:drop "
-6 -A LOGDROP -j LOG --log-prefix "ipt:6:drop "
   -A LOGDROP -j DROP
```

And I want to not repeat myself at the end of every chain. So it would be awesome if in the other chains I am jumping *from* I could already set strings such that I could assemble them in my `LOGDROP` chain into the `log-prefix`.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice idea. This would mean to create a variable and add it to all packets. I’m not aware of any possibility like this. But all hope is not lost: there could be a way to achieve similar thing.

You can use the MARK target:

```
iptables -A INPUT -j MARK --set-mark 123
```

Netfilter associates a 32 bit field to every packet. And its value will be logged with the LOG target. Then you could grep your logs for the string `MARK=0x7b` (7B = 123). If you want further match against this mark in the iptbles rules, you can do it with the `mark` match.

So it is not as nice as a string, but it may be satisfy your needs?

EDIT:
You can also set/unset only one or more specific bits with `--and-mark`,  `--or-mark` or `--xor-mark`, or with `--set-mark val/mask` which will give you quite some possibilities of marking packets, equivalent to concatenate strings.

The doc is there on the [netfilter's page](http://ipset.netfilter.org/iptables-extensions.man.html) in the part in the bottom, for the targets, (just to be precise, the match extension (-m) has the same name and is documented on the same page)

Comment: I guess it is one way of doing it. The annoying part is still that I'd have to spell it out everywhere in my rules. But this might get me closer to a solution.

Comment: @0xC0000022L, not sure what you mean but see the edit added and the link to the doc.

Comment: it'd be easier to set the prefix in stages. Using marks makes no tangible difference to the current solution I am already using. I was aware of marks, but they didn't seem to improve the situation I described and I still don't see how they do after reading your answer. With the possible exception that I could designate bits to IPv4 vs. IPv6 etc ... and then use a separate chain to build the log prefix in one go, matching the possible log prefixes (based on the used bits).